# remove everything after the last underscore of a column in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a dataframe and for a particular column I want to strip out everything after the last underscore.

So:

```
test <- data.frame(label=c('test_test_test', 'test_tom_cat', 'tset_eat_food', 'tisk - tisk'), 
                   stuff=c('blah', 'blag', 'gah', 'nah') , 
                   numbers=c(1,2,3, 4))
```

should become

```
result <- data.frame(label=c('test_test', 'test_tom', 'tset_eat', 'tisk - tisk'), 
                   stuff=c('blah', 'blag', 'gah', 'nah') , 
                   numbers=c(1,2,3, 4))
```

I have got:

```
require(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(label = gsub('_.*','',label))
```

but that drops everything from the first underscore and gives me

```
 wrong_result <- data.frame(label=c('test', 'test', 'tset', 'tisk - tisk'), 
                   stuff=c('blah', 'blag', 'gah', 'nah') , 
                   numbers=c(1,2,3, 4))
```

Comment: `test %>% mutate(label = gsub('_[^_]*$', '', label))`

Answer (score 16):

We can use `sub` and this can be done without any external packages

```
test$label <- sub("_[^_]+$", "", test$label)
test$label
#[1] "test_test"   "test_tom"    "tset_eat"    "tisk - tisk"
```

Answer (score 5):

This will also work:

```
gsub('(.*)_\\w+', '\\1', test$label)
#[1] "test_test"   "test_tom"    "tset_eat"    "tisk - tisk"
```